# There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south, psycopg2

I have a django app with version as `1.6.5`, i am trying to upgrade it to `1.8`, but on the way i got the below error right after the django version was increased  to `1.8`

```
There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Code

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django_messages',
    'avatar',
    'tinymce',
    'south',
    'tracking',
    ......
  ]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'NAME': 'xxxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        },
    }
```

So what was the problem and what need to be done to fix this ?

I have even tried with the below setting and receiving the same error when running the django local server

```
SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
    'default': "south.db. postgresql_psycopg2"
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution i found to the above problem was just removing the south from virtual environment apart from all the changes mentioned above

Comment: This is what caused the issue for me. `pip uninstall South` and my migrations worked.

Answer (score 9):

You are probably still referencing to South with an import somewhere.

Just:

```
pip uninstall south
```

Then:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And resolve import errors.

Answer (score 3):

Since Django 1.7, migrations are part of the framework. Instead of using South, you probably want to [migrate to django.db.migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south).

Generally speaking, you should always read release notes (for 1.7 and 1.8) when doing such an update.

Comment: Actually i removed south from installed_apps and still facing the same error as above, what should be the problem ?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south and done everything ? Removing south is only one of the steps.

Comment: Yeah i have done all the steps as indicated in the url

Answer (score 1):

Django with version >= 1.7 use built-in migration. You don't need to use south.

For more details about Django migration framework you can refer release note - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations

Django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

Upgading from South - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django < 1.7, you should also install South >= 1.0.1 if you haven’t already. This is not listed as a dependency for the sake of users who are on Django >= 1.7 and don’t need it.