# 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' error in django south settings

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south, psycopg2

I updated my django app(1.6.5) to 1.8 by referring [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) and removed south completely from my app. Now when i was trying to run django server i was getting below errors

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
client.Client.notes: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
tracking.BannedIP.ip_address: (fields.W900) IPAddressField has been deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 1.9.
    HINT: Use GenericIPAddressField instead.

System check identified 9 issues (0 silenced).
There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I have done a grep on my django app folder and sure i can't find south anywhere, so what was the problem and what is the fix to this problem

Comment: Do you have a `migrations` directory in your app that contains south migrations? If so, rename it to `south_migrations`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql\_psycopg2' for your database django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647602/there-is-no-south-database-module-south-db-postgresql-psycopg2-for-your-databa)

Comment: yeah i do have migrations folders in more than one app, as indicated by the official django docs, just deleted all the numbered files except __init__.py. So do you want me to change all the migration folder to south_migration in multiple apps ?

Comment: @Alasdair Do i have any fix here ?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) suggest deleting all of the migration files (but not `__init__.py`), and removing all `.pyc` files. If you've done that, and still get the error, then I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Do you have removed the tables, which stores the history of migrations?